# How to check if someone retweeted a tweet

Tags: twitter

I need to check if a user did in fact retweeted a tweet I asked him to. The user already has connected his twitter account with my application.

To check whether or not a user has  retweeted I'm using the api call http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/{id}/retweeted_by.json, which returns the first 100 users that retweeted the tweet with id {id}.

The problem is that I have to go through the 100 users, and the given user might not even be in the results, so I have to call the api again to get the next 100 users. This is costly and I want to know if there is an api call that can answer me this question, in a single call, with a single result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the user's feed for the retweet.

Comment: Ok but it could not be marked as a classic retweet in the user's feed. Imagine that the tweet is "blablabla". Some tweeps could retweet is with a classic simple tweet looking like "*RT @ignacio: blablabla*" (without retweet field) or "*"blablabla" (via @ignacio)*" (assuming *@ignacio* is the sender of the tweet).

Comment: The "blablabla" portion should be the same for both though.  Twitter's interface doesn't allow modification of the retweeted content as far as I can tell.  You should be able to string search within the tweet to compare the two.